# Dynamically change the background of div based on the returned value of function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the function

```
function getColor() {

  var color = '';

    $('.animated-teaser.cold').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      color = 'coldest';
      return color;
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      color = '';
      return color;
    }
  );

  $('.animated-teaser.warm').hover(
    function() {
     $(this).addClass('active');
      color = 'warmest';
      return color;
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      color = '';
      return color;
    }
  );
}
```

Then I call it

```
$('.area').css('background-color', getColor());
```

I see that the function it works, but the result doesn't affect the ".area" element.

I don't want to add an event to the ".area" element!

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v2wybrp/4/)

Comment: The `getColor` function attaches hovering listeners to DOM elements. That's all it does. It does not return a color. Currently, you're expecting this function to return a color from a future event that has not happened yet (the user hovering an element). The logic is flawed, you need to rethink it. First, attach the hovering listeners. Then, on hover, change the area color.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comments, the `getColor` function attaches hovering listeners to DOM elements. That's all it does. It does not return a color. Currently, you're expecting this function to return a color from a future event that has not happened yet (the user hovering an element). The logic is flawed, you need to rethink it. First, attach the hovering listeners. Then, on hover, change the area color.

```
const $area = $('.area'),
  $cold = $('.animated-teaser.cold'),
  $warm = $('.animated-teaser.warm');

$cold.hover(function() {
  $cold.addClass('active');
  changeAreaColor('coldest');
}, function() {
  $cold.removeClass('active');
  changeAreaColor('');
});

$warm.hover(function() {
  $warm.addClass('active');
  changeAreaColor('warmest');
}, function() {
  $warm.removeClass('active');
  changeAreaColor('');
});
}

function changeAreaColor(color) {
  $area.css('background-color', color)
}
```

This being said, `"warmest"` is an invalid CSS color, so it won't do anything. Change it to "crimson" or [something official](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Should be tying to the hover event instead of a one time update, i.e.

```
$('.area.animated-teaser.cold').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      color = 'coldest';
      return color;
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      color = '';
      return color;
    }
);
```

Comment: Returning a color in the future (at hover time) won't act on a function that was called in the past (at init time). This changes nothing to the flawed logic.

Comment: @JeremyThille of course you are correct, I was focused on the order being off and wasn’t paying attention to the underlying flawed logic

Comment: But in the end, that doesn't solve the problem at all :)

Comment: @JeremyThille understood, that is why I upvoted your answer

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is flawed for several reasons, not least of all due to the semantics of attaching event handlers in a function designed to return a colour value, which itself returns no value.

However, given your HTML, you don't need JS for this at all. You can do this more effectively in CSS by using the General sibling selector (`~`) and `:hover`.

Also note that `coldest` and `warmest` are not valid options for the `background-color` rule. You need to use a recognised colour name or value. In the following example I used `lightblue` and `coral`. Try this:

```css
.animated-teaser {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.animated-teaser:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.animated-teaser.cold {
  background: blue;
}

.animated-teaser.warm {
  background: orange;
}

.animated-teaser.cold:hover ~ .area {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.animated-teaser.warm:hover ~ .area {
  background-color: coral;
}

.area {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-teaser cold"></div>
<div class="animated-teaser warm"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
```

Comment: This was just an example. I need to return the value from this function because I will use it to another JS code. I'll pass this function as a value of property to another code :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put these 2 lines in CSS. No need of javascript for this simple task

```
.cold:hover ~ .area {
    background: blue
}
.warm:hover ~ .area {
    background: orange
}
```